# How to access a database using a selectedindexchanged method

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a data source being accessed in another class. I use this data source to populate my combobox on page load event. I have got to the point where my method is accessing the database off the selectedindexchanged event. It gives me the error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. I used breakpoints to see where it was failing. To my surprise it is collecting the first row of data (not the one I selected) and then it goes past breakpoit and gives me the error message. Why is it doing that since there is data in it right before?
My combobox fill method

```
try
        {
            List<PreviousVersionData> listID = PreviousVersionData.getDatabase();
            if (listID != null)
            {
                foreach (PreviousVersionData l in listID)
                {
                    cmboBoxPreviousVersion.Items.Add(l.FormatID.ToString() + " - " + l.FormatName);

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Here is where the problem lies, it gives me an error on the breakpoint i set on Item.FormatID = data.FormatID;

```
if (cmboBoxPreviousVersion.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            PreviousVersionData data = new PreviousVersionData();

            PreviousVersionData pvdata = new PreviousVersionData();
            data = pvdata.getDataByID(cmboBoxPreviousVersion.SelectedItem.ToString());

            Item.FormatID = data.FormatID;
            Item.FormatName = data.FormatName;
            Item.FormatDescription = data.FormatDescription;
            Item.StockID = data.StockID;
            Item.PrintPlantCode = (bool)data.PrintPlantCode;
            Item.PrintWeight = (bool)data.PrintWeight;
            Item.PrintPrice = (bool)data.PrintPrice;

            rChkBoxPlantCode.Checked = Item.PrintPlantCode;
            rChkBoxPrintPrice.Checked = Item.PrintPrice;
            rChkBoxWeight.Checked = Item.PrintWeight;
            cmboBoxStock.Items.Add(Item.StockID);
            rTxtBoxDescription.Text = Item.FormatDescription;
        }
```

I am new to using a class for database access I was always taught using a wizard. Is there a better method of getting that info into my fields or am I just a missing something somewhere? Thank you for your help. If you need clarification just let me know!

Comment: You are putting strings in your combobox, then using one such string to retrieve data from your database. Wouldn't it be more logical to use a key for that?
Apart from that, you are instantiating data, only to override it with pvdata.getDataById(). That seems hardly necessary :)
The error seesm to come from the fact that data i snull, meaning you did not find anything in your database where the KEY is equal to some concatenated string. That does not seem surprising.
That said, I do not know what Item is, it might be null too :)

Comment: trace getDataByID.  It appears data is null.  And no reason to new data if you are going to get it from getDataByID.   And why would you use a PreviousVersionData class to getDataByID rather than a static method?

Comment: @oerkelens what do you mean a key for that? So leave out pvdata.getetc?

Comment: I mean that getDataByID seems to retrieve an item by ID. But you are passing a string to it that is not only an ID, but a concatenated string containing key and name (and a dash).
You might want to fill your combobox with key-value pairs, displaying the value, and using the key to look up your data again.

Answer (score 1):

You'll be getting this error if `FormatID` is `null` here. The `ToString()` method can't executed against a `null` reference.

```
cmboBoxPreviousVersion.Items.Add(l.FormatID.ToString() + " - " + l.FormatName);
```

That's probably not what you want anyway, but to safeguard the code:

```
cmboBoxPreviousVersion.Items.Add(
    string.Format("{0} - {1}", l.FormatID, l.FormatName));
```

However, you also need to research why `FormatID` is `null` here.

Comment: @nepistheone i understand why it is null here I just do not know how to correct it

Comment: @CharmingInferno, the issue is in `PreviousVersionData.getDatabase`. You need to debug that code and find out why `FormatID` is getting a `null` value.